# Layout looks correct on my phone (Android) but not friend's (iPhone)

Tags: css

I finished the layout of the website I'm working on, and like how it looks...

[image]

But...when my friend opens it on her iPhone, it looks like this.

[image]

I can't figure out what's causing this. If I use Chrome Developer Tools and set it to a responsive mobile format, or iPhone X, it resizes properly. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

I also had a third person look at it who told me the video isn't playing. So I'm pretty lost, not sure what I'm doing wrong since I can't reproduce the issue myself.

[Here](https://stoic-snyder-620f18.netlify.app/) is the link if anyone wants to check.

And this is the code for the header.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import logo_image from "../../static/logo_white_trans.png"
import title_image from "../../static/title.png"

const MenuIcon = //Removed
const MenuLinks = //Removed

const Header = () => {
    const [nav, showNav] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div id='header' style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black', display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '20% 60% 20%' }}>
            <div id='logo' style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                <img alt='logo' src={logo_image} style={{ maxHeight: '15vh', maxWidth: '100%', width: 'auto !important' }} />
            </div>
            <div id='title' style={{ position: 'relative', margin: 'auto', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <img alt='title' src={title_image} style={{ maxHeight: '15vh', maxWidth: '100%', width: 'auto !important' }} />
            </div>
            <div id='menu' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <MenuIcon nav={nav} onClick={() => showNav(!nav)}>
                    <div />
                    <div />
                    <div />
                </MenuIcon>
                <MenuLinks nav={nav}>
                    <ul>
                        //Removed
                    </ul>
                </MenuLinks>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Header
```

And here is the index code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Header from "./header"
import Footer from "./footer"
import "./style.css"
import VideoFile from "../../resources/vide_file.mp4"

const Index = () => {
    const [nav, showNav] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <Header style={{ alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
            </Header >
            <video loop autoPlay muted style={{ preload: 'auto', height: "75vh", objectFit: "cover", display: "block", margin: "0 auto", alignItems: "stretch" }}>
                <source src={VideoFile} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <Footer style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            </Footer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index
```

Comment: So the main heading is the only issue? Which format are you shooting for?

Comment: The title div in the middle needs to resize to fit the available space without ever moving down to a new line. I know that's because I'm using flex, but someone suggested I use it. Previously I was using a table, but wasn't able to get the image to resize properly using grid template columns, which is why someone suggested I use flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight tweak to the `margin` property on your **div id='title'** element fixes the issue:

```
margin: '0 auto'
```

Remember that margin: 'auto' centers elements horizontally *and vertically*. I believe what's happening is Chromium is properly centering the element within the *direct* parent container, in this case:

```
<div id="header" style="height:100%;background-color:black;display:grid;grid-template-columns:20% 60% 20%"></div>
```

Safari instead is going a level up and centering the element on the grandparent, which is the full viewport height:

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"></div>
```

Specifying a '0' margin above and below the element forces Safari to move the logo back to the top of the parent element.